# How to use same code in Activity and WindowManager

Tags: android

I have activity its use this layout

```
mylayout.xml
```

and I program it onclick button etc ...

Now how can I use same code I program it and same xml layout in window manger not in activity. I just notice that's on facebook messenger

See image here 
[image]

Now this layout in activity and its same in `widnowManger`
I don't think they re programming it again in winowManger

And this in windowManger
any idea how can I do that's

[image]